# use headers and basic authentication in python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, basic-authentication

I have a test url

```
https://test.app.com/api/rest
```

In order to access the url and its contents, it is necessary to send headers as

```
headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"}
```

And also basic authentication is to be used, where credentials are

```
username=apple , password=ball
```

I have used

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

requests.post(URL,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password),
                                 data=data,
                                 headers=headers)
```

**Is this the correct way to send post request to a url also sending headers and basic authentication ?**

Comment: It looks fine, does it run well? Make sure the data is passed as a json string: `data=json.dumps(data)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general: yes, it seems alright.

But some notes/fixes/hints:

1. BasicAuth can be used as just tuple, so `auth=(username, password)` is enough - [docs say that BasicAuth is common that it they made it a shorthand](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)
2. When you do any request, you should save its result to know whether it was successful or nor and diagnose it. Usually `r = requests.post(...)` is enough. You can then either manually check `r.status_code` (and examine `r.content`) or do `r.raise_for_status()` to just get an error for 4xx and 5xx codes.

   `r.raise_for_status()` will raise an error only based on the code itself and what it seems. But sometimes `r.content` might provide info on what actually broke - e.g. "400 bad request", while response might have in its content what field is missing).
3. As for json headers and `data=data`... another shorthand. `data=` requires you to pass data in a form that you want it to be sent directly. But `requests` lib knows that a lot of times we want to send json data, so they implemented a `json=` arguments - which takes care of converting your dict/list structure to json for you and sets the `content-type` header as well!

So in your case:

```py
data = {"example": "data"}
r = requests.post(URL, # save the result to examine later
                  auth=(username, password), # you can pass this without constructor
                  json=data) # no need to json.dumps or add the header manually!
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want json data to be sent, just replace data with json. Other fields are okay.